# owl carousel list wont show after applying laravel's spatie/CSP

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, security, content-security-policy

I have a owl carousel list of images:

```
 <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen1.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen2.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen3.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen4.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen5.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen6.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen7.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen2.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen5.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen1.png')}}"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/app-screen/screen6.png')}}"></div>
</div>
```

which worked perfectly until I started using CSP i think there is something wrong with my rules(i'm using laravel's `spatie/laravel-csp` [package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp)) here are my rules:

```
 public function configure()
{
    $this->addDirective(Directive::BASE, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::CONNECT, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::DEFAULT, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::FORM_ACTION, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::IMG, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::MEDIA, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::OBJECT, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::SCRIPT, Value::SELF)
        ->addDirective(Directive::STYLE, Value::SELF);
}
```

note: owl carousel doesn't have any inline code and all js and css files are stored in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify Value::UNSAFE_INLINE as well as SELF

Comment: mark as correct or close it.